# Add default user field to WooCommerce checkout

Tags: filters, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic, user-meta, user-registration

trying to add default user meta field "nickname" to the standard woo commerce user checkout user field. The examples on their website adds custom fields to order_meta - but it seems the dont use standard wordpress form functions. I have this outlined example, but need to hook add_user_meta to woocommerce_form_field.

```
/**
* Add the field to the checkout
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'nickname', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Agency Name'),
    'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'nickname' ));

echo '</div>';

}

/**
* Process the checkout
*/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
// Check if set, if its not set add an error.
if ( ! $_POST['nickname'] )
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}

/**
* Update the user meta with field value
*/
add_action( 'user_hook', 'update_user_profile' );

function update_user_profile( $user_id ) {
   update_user_meta($user_id, 'nickname', $nickname);
}
```